# VBscript to count number of files created in last 5 minutes in specific folder

Tags: datetime, vbscript, count

VBScript to Count number of files in a specified folder created in last 5 minutes.

I would like to compare 5 different folders to check for last created file counts from last 5 minutes, if one of the folders is not getting updated with new files then I would like to flag an error.

I am able to find all file count within the folder.

But how do I find file count that are created within the last 5 minutes?

Program to Count number of files in a specified folder created in the last 5 minutes

```
Dim Files, Folder, objFSO

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")  
Set Folder = objFSO.GetFolder("my path")  

Files = Folder.Files.Count

MsgBox ("Number of Files =  " & Files)
```

If there are no files created in the last 5 minutes, then display 0.

Comment: Look for properties of `Files` items.

Comment: Iterate over `.Files` and increment a counter for each file whose creation date is less than 5 minutes ago.

Comment: OK, thanks. Do I have to iterate for all files in the folder to find last 5 minutes created file ? Or is there any way I can find now to last five minutes ?